MySQL 8.0.28 covering (and functional) index is not used
I am trying to use covering index (with a functional index) in MySQL 8.0.28 to speed up a group by query on a large InnoDB table.
Covering index created:
ALTER TABLE `sp_files`
ADD INDEX `ix_site_header_to_cleaned_text2` (`sp_site_foreign_key`, (length(`cleaned_text`)));

Using only the fields from the covering index I would expect that MySQL uses the index instead of the underlying table - so I would expect the Extra column of the output of the EXPLAIN to show Using index:
EXPLAIN
SELECT sp_site_foreign_key,
    count(case when length(`cleaned_text`) > 100 then 1 else NULL END) as num1,
    count(1) as num2
FROM sp_files USE INDEX (`ix_site_header_to_cleaned_text2`)
GROUP by sp_site_foreign_key; 




id
select_type
table
partitions
type
possible_keys
key
key_len
ref
rows
filtered
Extra




1
SIMPLE
sp_files

index
ix_site_header_to_cleaned_text2
ix_site_header_to_cleaned_text2
208

105249
100




Any idea why it is not using the index?
All fields of the query are contained in the ix_site_header_to_cleaned_text2 index, so I would expect the explain to show Using index in the Extra column.

It is using the index (hence the type: index join type shown in the EXPLAIN report), but it can't gain the covering index optimization.
MySQL's support for functional indexes has some limitations that you might not notice unless you read the manual very carefully:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/generated-column-index-optimizations.html

The optimizer can use indexes on generated columns to generate execution plans, even in the absence of direct references in queries to those columns by name. This occurs if the WHERE, ORDER BY, or GROUP BY clause refers to an expression that matches the definition of some indexed generated column.

This means it's supposed to allow you to use the same expression as the functional part of the index (in this case length(cleaned_text)), and automatically get that value from the index, so it doesn't have to recalculate it.
But this doesn't work if you use that expression in other clauses of the query, such as the select-list in your case, or in the JOIN clause. It doesn't implement this optimization in other clauses than those named in the manual description.
Perhaps they will improve support for functional indexes further in future versions of MySQL.
In the meantime, you may get the covering index only if you define a virtual column explicitly, and reference that column in the index and in your query.
Demo, tested on MySQL 8.0.36:
CREATE TABLE sp_files (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  sp_site_foreign_key INT,
  cleaned_text TEXT,
  other INT,
  length_cleaned_text INT AS (length(cleaned_text)) 
);

ALTER TABLE `sp_files`
ADD INDEX `ix_site_header_to_cleaned_text2` (`sp_site_foreign_key`, length_cleaned_text);

EXPLAIN
SELECT sp_site_foreign_key,
    count(case when length_cleaned_text > 100 then 1 else NULL END) as num1,
    count(1) as num2
FROM sp_files USE INDEX (`ix_site_header_to_cleaned_text2`)
GROUP by sp_site_foreign_key\G

Output:
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: sp_files
   partitions: NULL
         type: index
possible_keys: ix_site_header_to_cleaned_text2
          key: ix_site_header_to_cleaned_text2
      key_len: 10
          ref: NULL
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using index


Oh, you are right, I missed that part of the MySQL docs!!! I did not realize that the functional index's column can't be used in the SELECT. Thanks, the virtual column idea is gold. I have just implemented it and now the EXPLAIN does show Using index. THANKS!!!

I'm not a MySQL professional, but what if you surround ix_site_header_to_cleaned_text2 with the `` inside FROM sp_files USE INDEX (ix_site_header_to_cleaned_text2)?

Thanks, I have just tried that - no difference.
Which makes sense, as if it would not be able to pick that index up (because the name reference would be off), then it would not be showing that in the key column of the explain output. So it definitely gets that I want it to use the ix_site_header_to_cleaned_text2 index. To make sure that this doesn't confuse others, I have edited the original post with adding the ix_site_header_to_cleaned_text2 in between in theExplain` command.
